# How to work zRSSFeed with https

Tags: javascript, rss-reader

i'm using the zRSSFeed script to display RSS feeds. I found an issue when I'm using the script under https is not working and not showing the results. But it works if I replace the https to HTTP in the URL. I have added this into the javascript but is not working

how can I fix it?

```
<script src="js/jquery.zrssfeed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.contentText').rssfeed('http://feeds.feedburner.com/perishablepress', {
    limit: 5,
    ssl: true,
    target: '_blank',
    offset: 3,
    dateformat: 'datetime',
    snippet: false, 
    content: false

 });
});
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

review jQuery header file and using correct version.
pay attention to : "jquery.min.js"
i suggest you search for other rss :D